# Force user to pass by Facebook Login when deep linking

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

My APP is using a LoginActivity powered by Facebook SDK.

All works fine, apart when i want to do deep linking, because if i send directly the user to one part of my app, then the user bypass the *so called mandatory login*

So what i did is the following:

```
<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data
                android:host="myapp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/invitations"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

with the data scheme on the login activity, the user that receive the deep linking link is force to login, and then after login i redirect him directly to the right Activity as follow (algorythmic version):

```
private void onLoginSuccess(){

if (getIntent().getData() != null) {
//meaning the user come from a deep link 
    startActivityReview();
}
else{
//meaning the user just open the app withtout any arg from deep link
    goToNormalActivity();
   }
}
```

And i have to admit, it works perfectly, BUT of course **its not possible to get the data android:host on the launcher activity**

So i'm asking you, how could i force my user coming from a deep link to login first ? Could it be something like this?

> On the deep linked activity:

```
if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null){
     Intent main = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
     main.putExtra("action", "userNeedToComerbBackHereAfterLogin");
     startActivity(main);
}
```

> On the login activity

```
private void onLoginSuccess(){
     if (getIntent().getExtras().get("action") != null) {
         Intent main = new Intent(this, DeepLinkedAcitivty.class);
         startActivity(main);
     else{
       // Normal Behavior ...
     }
```

I feel that there must be a better way, is it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In your activity class you can check that your user is logged, and if not send him back on login. OR you make a deeplink activity that handle this behavouir, parse your deeplink and send your user to the correct activity.

Comment: Hi Ben-J , thanks for your answer, i edited my question while u were writing, would it be correct to you ?